# String Encryption using a key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, encryption

I am looking for a way to securely encrypt any credentials used in my source code, e.g. Credentials used to connect to a third party API

I have a question regarding encrypting a string or a file...

Take the following GitHub project: https://github.com/2Toad/Rijndael256/blob/master/README.md

I understand the encryption / decryption method but the part that confuses me is using a password that is hard coded to encrypt, surely if anyone gained access to your source code they could decrypt it anyway.

How would you go about making sure the password used to encrypt is also secure?

Comment: The password is provided by the user, why would the source code have the password?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear I will edit question, I have edited question

Comment: Alright, the question still remains.  Why would you store a password in your source code?  Passwords should be in configs, sensitive data should not be committed to source control

Comment: Thanks for that, would you go as far to encrypt sections of the config file or just store the credentials in a config file and ignore from source control, this also may seem like a silly question but does .net have built in functionality to stop anyone accessing the config file?

Comment: This gets asked a lot, the answer is simple: The executing code needs the decrypted data at some point, so a hacker is always able to get it. Your data is only as secure as the access to your PC.

Comment: Thanks that's a fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course a password is generally retrieved from a user. A computer doesn't have any use for a password; instead it can simply remember a key directly; humans are however pretty bad at remembering 128 bits (32 hex characters) or more .

There are many ways for a computer to retrieve a key; there is key agreement, there are key stores, key wrapping, key derivation, storage in hardware etc. etc. The entire handling of keys is the subject of books and is called *key management*.

Sometimes it does make sense to have keys in code / runtime memory. If the runtime is **less accessible** than the process itself to the user then it can give a small amount of protection. The same goes for configuration files, although both are generally readable by the user.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that generic questions on key management should be asked on security.stackexchange, not here on SO. Generic questions on the crypto behind it are welcome on the crypto.stackexchange site.